# Is allowing AnyMethod() and AnyHeader() secure with CORS for .Net 6?

Tags: c#, api, security, cors

We have an public facing web-server, with a custom `API` feature to allow users to download data associated with a website we've developed. It's just an option to give users the data behind the website, for their own personal use and in `json` format.

My question is not related to any errors or issues, as such. It's a question on security and if the way we've done it is safe.

I am new to CORS and wondered if doing this, is secure enough?

```
builder.Services.AddCors(p =>
    p.AddPolicy("corsapp", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
        }));
```

The data we provide is very limited and has no personal or identifiable information that would be of value to a hacker. In fact the data can be sourced from the internet in other websites.

Is the above `builder` *ok* as is, or should we be specific with our domain URL in case hackers get past the API's default protection? By default I mean we are not programming any ***specific security*** features into our API. I just built it using VS2022, with the default project template for API development in C#.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Please provide links or examples on how to properly setup `CORS` on an API ***without authentication***. As I said in my OP, our API does not require authentication - it's just a straight data dump. However, with the above `Builder`, we are concerned of other possible vulnerabilities (if any!) - OR is CORS by default is "safe"?!

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/227779/concrete-example-of-how-can-access-control-allow-origin-cause-security-risks/254684#254684

Comment: Thanks @jub0bs - that post made sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your use case it is safe (at least for you, **generally no**), with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) you are allowing browsers to initiate cross-origin HTTP request from scripts. (javascript) but you don't need this (your users are downloading from the same site, and probably not with js).

What is CORS?: ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#how-cors)):

- Is a W3C standard that allows a server to relax the ***same-origin policy***.
- Is not a security feature, ***CORS relaxes security***. An API is not safer by allowing CORS.
- Allows a server to explicitly allow some cross-origin requests while rejecting others.

If your API is used from the same domain only (subdomains count as a different origins, also scheme counts as a different origin (*http* vs *https*), ports too), then you don't have to use **CORS**.

By default nothing is allowed, but if you want to provide access to some other sites to access your resources (from different domains), then you can allow that site some selected methods. (add them as exception - the sites you trust)

You can also limit in your controller to just allow on some methods (not globally), that way you minimize the attack surface.

Note: in first try I would disable CORS (it is disabled by default), and if nothing breaks, you never needed to enable it (if you need to enable it, do it in the most strict way - see source above).

Comment: So it's *not* safe, because that disables CORS and allows a malicious script to load anything else it likes

Comment: In most cases it is not safe (for example if you could change the password of users), but if you look at the use case (for downloading files) it is safe.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you elaborate or provide links to examples on how to properly setup CORS on an API without authentication? As I said in my OP, our API does not require authentication - it's just a straight data dump. However, with the above Builder, we are concerned of other possible vulnerabilities (if any).